# Setting debugging traces when running tests on Intellij

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

Does interactive debugging work when running tests inside Intellij ? I'm setting traces before running tests, but tests are run and I am never given control to debug.

When running tests I get `Error running PipelinesTest: Invalid arguments : Already listening [timeout, port, localAddress]`. But then tests are run and I'm not given control.

Comment: Are you sure you're using "Debug <class name>" instead of "Run <class name>"? To stop at breakpoints, you need to debug the test, not just run it.

Comment: Yes. I'm right clicking on the test class and using "Debug"

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's the problem until you provide the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I know, but I don't really know what more information to provide in this case. It seems to be something related to Intellij configuration and I'm a complete noob with this IDE. What information should I provide ?

Comment: What run/debug configuration type do you use? Do you specify any custom VM options?

Comment: I'm using the default. http://imgur.com/a/QRtqv

Comment: Please try to uncheck "Use sbt" setting.

Comment: Awesome. That worked !

Answer (score 3):

The problem was that apparently the debugger doesn't work when having "Use sbt" checkbox activated in the intellij config type.